# Ошибка 404 на GitHub Pages?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Не могу понять почему не отображается сайт.
Залил файлы на созданный репозиторий с именем вида `username.github.io`.
Все успешно залил, но при переходе на GitHub Pages ошибка 404, при том что файл `index.html` лежит в корне.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У меня ткая же проблема, ищу решение
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1564798/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-github-pages?noredirect=1#comment2819995_1564798

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В названии репозитория "username.github.io" нужно изменить "**username**" на свой логин.