# GitHub как хостинг

Tags: html, css, github, хостинг

Сделал репозиторию на сайте github залил туда все файлы с кодом. Начал запускать ссылку, а там ошибка 404. Уже переделывал несколько раз - все равно та же ошибка. 
Что посоветуете? Я использовал заместо username свой логин, а не слово username.

Comment: Это означает, что сервер не может найти данные согласно запросу. Перечитайте внимательно как GitHub Pages правильно использовать.

Comment: Вот тут можно найти ответы: https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка 404 на github page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696467/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-404-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github-page)

Comment: подожди минут 10. Бывает просто долго обрабатывает.